# You 'looks' ugly or you 'look' ugly?

Tags: grammar

Which one is grammatically correct? Look or looks in a sentence "You ____ ugly". And difference between look & looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You look ugly" is correct.

"You" is second person.  the "-s" is used for singular third person nouns and pronouns.

- "I look ugly."
- "You look ugly."
- "He/She/It looks ugly."
- "They look ugly."

Comment: As FumbleFingers has said, '… we should seek to discourage people from providing trivial answers to trivial questions.... We all like to be helpful, but the place for that level of help is English Language Learners'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough